# Opendaylight Karaf errors while it installs boot features

Tags: apache-karaf, apache-felix, opendaylight, apache-karaf-feature

I'm trying to start Opendaylight Nemo from [GitHub repo code](https://github.com/opendaylight/nemo) and after a long time spent in resolving dependencies version and replacing some old methods(now deprecated or not supported) I managed to build the code. However, when I start Karaf and it tries to install the boot features I got this error

```
org.apache.felix.resolver.reason.ReasonException: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=18f63ee6-cf11-4378-a68f-e917667362bf; type=karaf.feature; version="[0,0.0.0]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=18f63ee6-cf11-4378-a68f-e917667362bf)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=0.0.0)(version<=0.0.0))"
[caused by: Unable to resolve 18f63ee6-cf11-4378-a68f-e917667362bf/0.0.0: missing requirement [18f63ee6-cf11-4378-a68f-e917667362bf/0.0.0] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=standard; type=karaf.feature; version="[4.3.2,4.3.2]"
[caused by: Unable to resolve standard/4.3.2: missing requirement [standard/4.3.2] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=pax-url-wrap; type=karaf.feature
[caused by: Unable to resolve pax-url-wrap/2.6.7: missing requirement [pax-url-wrap/2.6.7] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=org.ops4j.pax.url.wrap; type=osgi.bundle; version="[2.6.7,2.6.7]"; resolution:=mandatory 
[caused by: Unable to resolve org.ops4j.pax.url.wrap/2.6.7: missing requirement [org.ops4j.pax.url.wrap/2.6.7] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.repository)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=1.2.0)))"
[caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.karaf.features.core/4.3.2: missing requirement [org.apache.karaf.features.core/4.3.2] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.cm.json)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))"]]]]]
[caused by: Unable to resolve 18f63ee6-cf11-4378-a68f-e917667362bf/0.0.0: missing requirement [18f63ee6-cf11-4378-a68f-e917667362bf/0.0.0]
[caused by: Unable to resolve standard/4.3.2: missing requirement [standard/4.3.2] 
[caused by: Unable to resolve pax-url-wrap/2.6.7: missing requirement [pax-url-wrap/2.6.7]
[caused by: Unable to resolve org.ops4j.pax.url.wrap/2.6.7: missing requirement [org.ops4j.pax.url.wrap/2.6.7]
[caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.karaf.features.core/4.3.2: missing requirement [org.apache.karaf.features.core/4.3.2] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.felix.cm.json)(version>=1.0.0)
```

Following the errors chain I thought that the error is due **org.apache.felix.cm.json** that is the only missing package in all of the displayed errors. I tried also to add the jar file manually but it doesn't work;
how can I resolve it?